# Routing 2 layer PCB: is it ok "solve" isolated GND island with a VIA?

Tags: pcb-layers, via

Every time that I design a PCB I connect the TOP layer and BOTTOM layer to GND (GND pour).
With this PCB I finally ended with an "isolated island", without possibility to use the TOP or BOTTOM layer as GND. I did added a VIA near the cap, but is it a good choice? And if yes, what's the raccomended dimension for the hole for the via?

This is the picture:

[image]

Update: PCB without the VIA and Eagle complaining:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by your definition of island.. but that aside I see two GND pins adjacent to those caps on the 328P..why the via.

Comment: Without that VIA, the GNDs of the two caps are not connected, Eagle complain about airwires.... I added an image without that VIA.

Comment: That's fine..but u can route to pin 8 or 22 .. and run that Vcc above the cap not below it.

Comment: @Trevor you are right! I can connect and "solve". Bytheway, only to learn, is better connect to 22 or create the VIA? The via is the "devil"?

Comment: Rerouting Vcc above will give you the space for the ground to connect / fill to pin 8.

Comment: Better to have as few vias as you can manage.

Comment: @Trevor last question, pls: Is it better to have 3 wires from VCC, 1 to first caps, 1 to second caps, 1 to another resistor (etcetera going to the rest of pcb) OR can I use only a wire from VCC to 1st caps, from 1st caps going to 2nd one and finally from 2nd one to other parts of pcb?

Comment: The latter would depend on the board and what "other parts" means. Less total length is usually better, but you may need the first device to be more "isolated". I certainly cant tell from that snippet.